# Not able to send mail of Hotmail with your own postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server, centos6, email-bounces

I purchased `DigitalOcean VPS` in that installing [cwp.admin](http://centos-webpanel.com/) open source panel.

Also all configuration completed like `postfix`,`rDNS`,`DKIM`,`DMARC`,`SPF`,`DNS Settings`,`etc`...

My problem is not able to send mail into `Hotmail` while same configuration to send mail to `Gmail` and other email provider.

When I sending mail Undeliverable:Message receive by `postmaster@outlook.com`

**Diagnostic information for administrators:**

```
Generating server: PN1PR01MB0031.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM

nXXXXXXX@hotmail.com
PN1PR01MB0031.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
Remote Server returned '532 5.3.2 STOREDRV.Deliver; Missing or bad mailbox Database property'

Original message headers:

Received: from BM1PR01CA0050.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (10.163.199.22) by
 PN1PR01MB0031.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (10.164.138.139) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (TLS) id 15.1.443.12; Thu, 31 Mar 2016 18:12:57 +0000
Received: from BO1IND01FT007.eop-IND01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:f400:7ea5::201) by BM1PR01CA0050.outlook.office365.com
 (2a01:111:e400:5a4a::22) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 15.1.447.15 via
 Frontend Transport; Thu, 31 Mar 2016 18:12:57 +0000
Received: from SNT004-MC3F20.hotmail.com (10.152.202.53) by
 BO1IND01FT007.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.202.83) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (TLS) id 15.1.443.6 via Frontend Transport; Thu, 31 Mar 2016 18:12:55
 +0000
Received: from DOMAIN_NAME.COM ([104.236.2.88]) by SNT004-MC3F20.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
     Thu, 31 Mar 2016 11:12:52 -0700
Received: from DOMAIN_NAME.COM (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by DOMAIN_NAME.COM (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 38F2945446
    for <nXXXXXXX@hotmail.com>; Thu, 31 Mar 2016 18:04:15 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=DOMAIN_NAME.COM;
    s=DOMAIN_NAME.COM; t=1459447455;
    bh=dHaWz8iYyjo/0rsH1scL0xRWrBaObwch4WPMkC804aM=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject:In-Reply-To:References;
    b=oS+kHpAITJ5R40Os4rgPK/rblplhehDhGFZWmPFeaEKLgrLUlvOyGXxVK7+WfQ+IF
     hBkALkFKrUFXy5fir7vz6f5WfkATLOsoA2acZKXwO2hj20Qm8UIP8Ir1AisTxgwZdd
     ZJi/rJlAkj1n1YaoTSG8bf6NqxDurhk7MszyuCes=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2016 23:34:15 +0530
From: sender name <sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM>
To: <nXXXXXXX@hotmail.com>
Subject: Re: Fwd: Campaign started
Organization: DOMAIN_NAME
In-Reply-To: <1dd59691aa7e5d9bf9939af32794913f@DOMAIN_NAME.COM>
References: <d27ac96d4dbf85ff4548ccf2ffae5734@DOMAIN_NAME.COM>
 <1dd59691aa7e5d9bf9939af32794913f@DOMAIN_NAME.COM>
Message-ID: <0f99e4e4147380232e3db9823bc50fab@DOMAIN_NAME.COM>
X-Sender: sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM
Return-Path: sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 31 Mar 2016 18:12:52.0313 (UTC) FILETIME=[F0D2AC90:01D18B78]
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
CMM-sender-ip: 104.236.2.88
CMM-sending-ip: 104.236.2.88
CMM-Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 104.236.2.88;
 identity alignment result is pass and alignment mode is relaxed)
 smtp.mailfrom=sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM; dkim=pass (identity alignment result is
 pass and alignment mode is relaxed) header.d=DOMAIN_NAME.COM; x-hmca=pass
 header.id=sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM
CMM-X-SID-PRA: sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM
CMM-X-AUTH-Result: PASS
CMM-X-SID-Result: PASS
CMM-X-Message-Status: n:n
CMM-X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MztHRD0zO1NDTD03
CMM-X-Message-Info: quWoRize8kC5CusEkEaELQUwme2zurnbiD1m7xUsaMPji354B9ww/xmGAB5aGoYdcn0ZH+hirh+jqSsRwnc/THZoPdYPNgpZAZXUTH9RiDWLFX/FBvFiU95touPAMKaQxAsTK3Ljos+VyQLUrdZie9ml29M7uEA2RIYulCcUrEnJ+gwPZ3+XKBj0KWrgflyMUBHtMyJjRx2XC97PEkN665BOUOGqHQuwW3bgXrgET34=
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report:
    EFV:NLI;SFV:SKS;SFS:;DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:7;SRVR:PN1PR01MB0031;H:SNT004-MC3F20.hotmail.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:en;
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 701141fc-9e5d-4506-9b2d-08d359901632
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;PN1PR01MB0031;2:iKoGjNwpGEgtISZlktr+ENvwxwz+UXOcmBO75SZo/63b7xky/kGxYNfCOW5wEXx/8zV7NDxibo2FQdF+dpX4RDqbbxjNv2sE3jStM+0tQJQFfnm6KCTtrobPN0mR5PrVBA5ed7fxzLWAudbE4r8KQ/2V2n3VtMP/6rgn+S2c7isp7wyrdOLh5YcjL09jmovtCy+2nWMxjX/56r74FVoJaw==;3:OxRSQFJNP10Cf0nlAjqAyKIFi2IID8E5fVv3CfoSWE5SQ79zDNkudk5T8+6Jd8iixyjrRaPn+QlthnkLpBGwBKQvIjkbD6eeEMaMgBVIOKTU0UD41eews/dyAlElC0hLfHAw8cOp7LepFZEH7+ZRKJUVWcAhRPQe55UNi1GNkC0=;25:lcr0qtJVlNxEQxwZuhSBVEh2/0yUx2gw4WSrpy6ZNOqdLXbOtVTq2v8IiIMnTU2WgKekZIUjeLo6dwxxOJDkGQQ4NrN9DfhWClZ0D8jzIZRXIHck49RTw1OkWIHRQzClNhg3V7+k6xHdJxqrfuHmwQq/0OaNwf3B4VtQRWvCTihxnVG1YexjeCPJ1naSGcuQrVpn1Ck2WGMNZRHAyX0TiC2ZWUx1fn0bBKyNh3WifphXYl/bL8pu+7HywjEvmzsMrVt95uS35NMzEhyjO+Q2Yj9wPXSb1kbij9BDseKETp3JcVLVlCOafC5oObEmfNwi
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(8291501002);SRVR:PN1PR01MB0031;
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test:
    BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(82015046);SRVR:PN1PR01MB0031;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:PN1PR01MB0031;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    1;PN1PR01MB0031;4:l/tqhGzE/FqSkBuoJWDr52qD3IYfK0yHBHL0Syb5hUaR3WcXc+xty+XvH74sifyVhLW5D8wEc4pR8o8S6I5y0JUSrODi9uXNSs+C1FU+gIchC+r8xFKuD3Ib54sXjyZPHd+eNneR4lDhSvGsEYltnbOmKMRaa9+iOIPKA2ba981wyFJcZCRqgRdqJJf5CFA/P5PfCQ3t2VEYtrwTRnRaoZ7+oBH0H6+KnJHKW1/WqVa3qZ4TuQLV6VnQlONltw6+mcGc3DVCCDcU6JlDTOuCyQ==;23:+OJ3GU4Sc6lGFRzy6KrOaVRhD1vAaX9XvMNZ7HvDSSsX0VTwowyhNA0q5ftgNEgE7XmFUYOP5Fmka2ee5JMBQC+MzuYez0ZEXb85pOW/Ga+apL2/9IkM0Y6FGqX6JVr5Fo/FZ2kVhaGthHnrFPZ0q3sW+m0s7mOKJkwcIHflfKp8dw4OWY/dCAvdQ2kZNJw+;5:GHYRkCjy7aWBbTWlOffjra5CEq/roG6u9yV5F8rCOc3fHHAYOdemuSMyCsVCNq/lM8PUx1+mzK2tBMAYBsbulQRTKjZ3GKPRIeTGxBMi1S5QUB5e9vrb2mL12me2gpq/JJgORYmUY7PpM74XXQq9dA==;24:ffDnkSsNbdRCldzF8jg6jSef7TwXto5tYvkzYfACt0kdr3zK0alSJKHn32Xb9RIUtB92N4URc6dbXG2OCkD4cQ==
SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:23
SpamDiagnosticMetadata: SKS
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 31 Mar 2016 18:12:55.4449
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: PN1PR01MB0031
 Reporting-MTA: dns;PN1PR01MB0031.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
Received-From-MTA: dns;SNT004-MC3F20.hotmail.com
Arrival-Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2016 18:12:57 +0000

Final-Recipient: rfc822;nXXXXXXX@hotmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.3.2
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;532 5.3.2 STOREDRV.Deliver; Missing or bad mailbox Database property
Remote-MTA: dns;PN1PR01MB0031.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM

Received: from BM1PR01CA0050.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (10.163.199.22) by
 PN1PR01MB0031.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM (10.164.138.139) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (TLS) id 15.1.443.12; Thu, 31 Mar 2016 18:12:57 +0000
Received: from BO1IND01FT007.eop-IND01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:f400:7ea5::201) by BM1PR01CA0050.outlook.office365.com
 (2a01:111:e400:5a4a::22) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 15.1.447.15 via
 Frontend Transport; Thu, 31 Mar 2016 18:12:57 +0000
Received: from SNT004-MC3F20.hotmail.com (10.152.202.53) by
 BO1IND01FT007.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.202.83) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (TLS) id 15.1.443.6 via Frontend Transport; Thu, 31 Mar 2016 18:12:55
 +0000
Received: from DOMAIN_NAME.COM ([104.236.2.88]) by SNT004-MC3F20.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
     Thu, 31 Mar 2016 11:12:52 -0700
Received: from DOMAIN_NAME.COM (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by DOMAIN_NAME.COM (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 38F2945446
    for <nXXXXXXX@hotmail.com>; Thu, 31 Mar 2016 18:04:15 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=DOMAIN_NAME.COM;
    s=DOMAIN_NAME.COM; t=1459447455;
    bh=dHaWz8iYyjo/0rsH1scL0xRWrBaObwch4WPMkC804aM=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject:In-Reply-To:References;
    b=oS+kHpAITJ5R40Os4rgPK/rblplhehDhGFZWmPFeaEKLgrLUlvOyGXxVK7+WfQ+IF
     hBkALkFKrUFXy5fir7vz6f5WfkATLOsoA2acZKXwO2hj20Qm8UIP8Ir1AisTxgwZdd
     ZJi/rJlAkj1n1YaoTSG8bf6NqxDurhk7MszyuCes=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Thu, 31 Mar 2016 23:34:15 +0530
From: Sender Name <sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM>
To: <nXXXXXXX@hotmail.com>
Subject: Re: Fwd: Campaign started
Organization: DOMAIN_NAME
In-Reply-To: <1dd59691aa7e5d9bf9939af32794913f@DOMAIN_NAME.COM>
References: <d27ac96d4dbf85ff4548ccf2ffae5734@DOMAIN_NAME.COM>
 <1dd59691aa7e5d9bf9939af32794913f@DOMAIN_NAME.COM>
Message-ID: <0f99e4e4147380232e3db9823bc50fab@DOMAIN_NAME.COM>
X-Sender: sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM
Return-Path: sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 31 Mar 2016 18:12:52.0313 (UTC) FILETIME=[F0D2AC90:01D18B78]
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
CMM-sender-ip: 104.236.2.88
CMM-sending-ip: 104.236.2.88
CMM-Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 104.236.2.88;
 identity alignment result is pass and alignment mode is relaxed)
 smtp.mailfrom=sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM; dkim=pass (identity alignment result is
 pass and alignment mode is relaxed) header.d=DOMAIN_NAME.COM; x-hmca=pass
 header.id=sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM
CMM-X-SID-PRA: sender@DOMAIN_NAME.COM
CMM-X-AUTH-Result: PASS
CMM-X-SID-Result: PASS
CMM-X-Message-Status: n:n
CMM-X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MztHRD0zO1NDTD03
CMM-X-Message-Info: quWoRize8kC5CusEkEaELQUwme2zurnbiD1m7xUsaMPji354B9ww/xmGAB5aGoYdcn0ZH+hirh+jqSsRwnc/THZoPdYPNgpZAZXUTH9RiDWLFX/FBvFiU95touPAMKaQxAsTK3Ljos+VyQLUrdZie9ml29M7uEA2RIYulCcUrEnJ+gwPZ3+XKBj0KWrgflyMUBHtMyJjRx2XC97PEkN665BOUOGqHQuwW3bgXrgET34=
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: EFV:NLI;SFV:SKS;SFS:;DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:7;SRVR:PN1PR01MB0031;H:SNT004-MC3F20.hotmail.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:en;
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 701141fc-9e5d-4506-9b2d-08d359901632
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;PN1PR01MB0031;2:iKoGjNwpGEgtISZlktr+ENvwxwz+UXOcmBO75SZo/63b7xky/kGxYNfCOW5wEXx/8zV7NDxibo2FQdF+dpX4RDqbbxjNv2sE3jStM+0tQJQFfnm6KCTtrobPN0mR5PrVBA5ed7fxzLWAudbE4r8KQ/2V2n3VtMP/6rgn+S2c7isp7wyrdOLh5YcjL09jmovtCy+2nWMxjX/56r74FVoJaw==;3:OxRSQFJNP10Cf0nlAjqAyKIFi2IID8E5fVv3CfoSWE5SQ79zDNkudk5T8+6Jd8iixyjrRaPn+QlthnkLpBGwBKQvIjkbD6eeEMaMgBVIOKTU0UD41eews/dyAlElC0hLfHAw8cOp7LepFZEH7+ZRKJUVWcAhRPQe55UNi1GNkC0=;25:lcr0qtJVlNxEQxwZuhSBVEh2/0yUx2gw4WSrpy6ZNOqdLXbOtVTq2v8IiIMnTU2WgKekZIUjeLo6dwxxOJDkGQQ4NrN9DfhWClZ0D8jzIZRXIHck49RTw1OkWIHRQzClNhg3V7+k6xHdJxqrfuHmwQq/0OaNwf3B4VtQRWvCTihxnVG1YexjeCPJ1naSGcuQrVpn1Ck2WGMNZRHAyX0TiC2ZWUx1fn0bBKyNh3WifphXYl/bL8pu+7HywjEvmzsMrVt95uS35NMzEhyjO+Q2Yj9wPXSb1kbij9BDseKETp3JcVLVlCOafC5oObEmfNwi
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(8291501002);SRVR:PN1PR01MB0031;
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(82015046);SRVR:PN1PR01MB0031;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:PN1PR01MB0031;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;PN1PR01MB0031;4:l/tqhGzE/FqSkBuoJWDr52qD3IYfK0yHBHL0Syb5hUaR3WcXc+xty+XvH74sifyVhLW5D8wEc4pR8o8S6I5y0JUSrODi9uXNSs+C1FU+gIchC+r8xFKuD3Ib54sXjyZPHd+eNneR4lDhSvGsEYltnbOmKMRaa9+iOIPKA2ba981wyFJcZCRqgRdqJJf5CFA/P5PfCQ3t2VEYtrwTRnRaoZ7+oBH0H6+KnJHKW1/WqVa3qZ4TuQLV6VnQlONltw6+mcGc3DVCCDcU6JlDTOuCyQ==;23:+OJ3GU4Sc6lGFRzy6KrOaVRhD1vAaX9XvMNZ7HvDSSsX0VTwowyhNA0q5ftgNEgE7XmFUYOP5Fmka2ee5JMBQC+MzuYez0ZEXb85pOW/Ga+apL2/9IkM0Y6FGqX6JVr5Fo/FZ2kVhaGthHnrFPZ0q3sW+m0s7mOKJkwcIHflfKp8dw4OWY/dCAvdQ2kZNJw+;5:GHYRkCjy7aWBbTWlOffjra5CEq/roG6u9yV5F8rCOc3fHHAYOdemuSMyCsVCNq/lM8PUx1+mzK2tBMAYBsbulQRTKjZ3GKPRIeTGxBMi1S5QUB5e9vrb2mL12me2gpq/JJgORYmUY7PpM74XXQq9dA==;24:ffDnkSsNbdRCldzF8jg6jSef7TwXto5tYvkzYfACt0kdr3zK0alSJKHn32Xb9RIUtB92N4URc6dbXG2OCkD4cQ==
SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:23
SpamDiagnosticMetadata: SKS
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 31 Mar 2016 18:12:55.4449
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: PN1PR01MB0031
```

Might be some place I make silly mistake can anybody help me out.

Thanks
Nimit Parekh

Comment: The error message you get `532 5.3.2 STOREDRV.Deliver; Missing or bad mailbox Database property'` is consistent with [KB 2983207](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2983207) and has everything to do with the recipient and nothing to with your sending mailserver, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @HBruijn I try many but still not working.

Comment: What do you want us to do? We are not Hotmail. We cannot fix Hotmail's problems.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i am not saying that you are hotmail I just here post question for if this kind of problem any body solve that people gave me hint.for information this questiom I am not pointing you directly here so mind your language.

Comment: You've already been given the hint!